# Grails and hudson plugin issue

Tags: grails, hudson, spring-security

I'm developing my first project in Grails framework. I'm using Spring Security Core plugin. On my machine, on newest IntelliJ Idea everything works fine. I can run, test and so on with no problems. 
I have a remote machine with subversion where I upload my code and Hudson with Grails Plugin. Target which I call on my hudson builds is:

```
"test-app --non-interactive"
```

When I run build, everything goes fine - plugins are downloaded and then, bam!

```
Resolving plugin JAR dependencies ...

:: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES :: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: org.springframework#org.springframework.test;3.0.5.RELEASE: configuration not found in org.springframework#org.springframework.test;3.0.5.RELEASE: 'master'. It was required from org.grails.internal#League;0.1 test
```

[Here](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/319617/) I put whole output from Hudson Console of this project build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a dependency issue with the Mail plugin, try going back to a non-snaphot version. I think 1.0 will be out shortly but see if 0.9 works.

Grails will automatically install the plugins it needs, you don't need to do anything manual on the build server.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install the plugin of the remote machine. Because the plugins are not included in the code. The plugin will be installed under your_home/.grails/grails_version/plugins (or  project/your_project).